# Code Contracts and ASP.NET MVC Controller properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-contracts

I am using CodeContracts for the first time, and I have a question regarding it. When I use `ModelState`, `User`, `Request` or `Response` in my controller code then Code Contracts is saying that I should add a `Contract.Requires(this.Request != null)` to my code.

**Message example:**

> Warning   1   CodeContracts: Missing precondition in an externally visible
>   method. Consider adding Contract.Requires(this.ModelState != null);
>   for parameter validation

I thought I could make those messages disappears from code-contracts by adding:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant()
{
    Contract.Invariant(this.HttpContext != null);
    Contract.Invariant(this.ModelState != null);
    Contract.Invariant(this.Request != null);
    Contract.Invariant(this.Response != null);
    Contract.Invariant(this.RouteData != null);
    Contract.Invariant(this.Server != null);
    Contract.Invariant(this.Session != null);
    Contract.Invariant(this.ViewData != null);
    Contract.Invariant(this.User != null);
    Contract.Invariant(this.Url != null);
}
```

To my code. But the ObjectInvariant function is checked at runtime before Controller.Initialize is called thus proving all invariants false.

---

**TL;DR**

Now my questions is, how can I disable those code contracts messages for controller base properties?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't use Code Contracts in your MVC controllers. Code Contracts are more useful in describing the preconditions and postconditions for methods called on objects in your Domain model (e.g. "business layer"), and not so much in the "application layer".

At the application layer, it's more suitable to perform traditional input validation. Also, of course, you'd want to have some integration tests (i.e. tests that exercise the system from the Controller down to at least the domain model layer, if not all the way down to the persistence store itself).

Answer (score -1):

What you can try is catching the ContractFailed event and suppress the exception in it, here's how to set it:

```
Contract.ContractFailed += (sender, args) => 
{ 
   //additionally you can check args.FailureKind to distinguish what exactly has failed (if needed)

   args.SetHandled(); 
};
```

Not sure however, if it suppresses error or just prevents it from bubbling up in a call stack. Another option to eliminate the warning message is to annotate a controller with the attribute:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Contracts", "Invariant")]
//or this: [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1062:Validate arguments of public methods")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Contract.Requires(Request != null);
    //...
    return View();
}
```

or to disable verification at all:

```
[ContractVerification(false)]
```

As for invariants - it will just add an extra call at the end of every public method and constructor(s) in your controller to perform your checks, but most of them is nonsense (especially Contract.Invariant(this.Request != null))

Comment: The ContractFailed event will not fire because it is a warning message generated by the Static Checker, The SuppressMessage will not work because The warning is not about the Invariants. And I do not wish to disable verification because that is the reason we started to use it.

Comment: Ok, if your warning is not about the invariant, then you could use what it is complaining about instead of invariant. Still most of your checks does not make any sense in scope of MVC controller

Comment: Btw, as for disabling by using ContractVerification attribute - you can disable checking at class or method level as well, not assembly level only. Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: True, but most of the logic will be done inside the Controller, so I do want the controller to be checked, I just don't want it to wine about Controller base properties.

Comment: And how would you suppress the warning based on my example in my question?

Comment: For that you need the code of actual warning, so that it will be similar to this: [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1062:Validate arguments of public methods")].

Comment: That is the whole point. It is NOT a code analysis warning, it is a code contracts warning. and the warning (as you can read in my example) does not show a code like CA1062 or something.

Comment: Ok, how about such workaround: Contract.Assume(Request != null) instead of Contract.Requires?

Comment: I currently use Assume, but I dont want to need to use Assume on almost every action method of every controller. So I was wondering if it is possible to make some sort of class wide Assume, as in the constructor or in the like the Invariants kind of way.

Answer (score -1):

The answer lies in the error "Missing precondition in an externally visible method". Your method is private. Try public void ObjectInvariant()